# Unity - PlayerPrefs not saving in standalone

Tags: unity-game-engine

A friend asked me to help him with his game, which has been programmed by two other programmers. One of them was not very clear and so parts of the code are messed up, but that's not the problem.

This game allows the player to edit and save new levels. The former programmers used PlayerPrefs to store every single data of them in it, instead of a struct or a class object (I don't see the point in it, but reprogramming everything would take some time I don't have).

What I did: I added a new parameter for each level, called Difficulty. When saved in the editor, the levels should save in order (from Easy A-Z to Hard A-Z). I made two general functions to save/load levels, which basically are getString/setString and getInt/setInt, which I call to store and retrieve them. And it works fine, on my computer.

The problem: When built, people who don't have Unity can't save a new edited level nor update the one they're editing. PlayerPrefs is just not storing the information.
However, it does on mine. I change things in the editor, and they happen correctly. I start a build (.exe) on my computer of the game, and it does save. Weird thing I notice is that in my computer at least, editor and build share the same info, so if I save or edit a level, the changes will last for the editor and viceversa.

As a side note, they didn't program an "exit" button or at least I haven't found it yet, so I have to alt+f4 to exit. I added PlayerPref.Save() at the end of the saveLevel function, but it did nothing. It shouldn't matter, since when I got the game, it was functional and saved correctly.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Insert sorted a new level:

```
public void SaveLevel()
{
    if (inputLevelName != null)
    {
        SortBeatList(); 

        // - Get difficulty chosen by the player
        string trackDiff = "";

        if (easyDifficulty.isOn == true)
        {
            trackDiff = " (Easy)";
        } 
        else if (mediumDifficulty.isOn == true)
        {
            trackDiff = " (Medium)";
        } 
        else if (hardDifficulty.isOn == true)
        { 
            trackDiff = " (Hard)";
        }

        string auxDiff = PlayerPrefs.GetString (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("CurrentLevel") + "Difficulty");
        string auxName = PlayerPrefs.GetString (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("CurrentLevel") + "Name");

        // - Save current level
        if (inputLevelName.text.CompareTo (auxName) == 0 && CompareDifficulties(trackDiff, auxDiff) == 0)
        {               
            SaveTrackInPosition(PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("CurrentLevel"), inputLevelName.text, trackDiff, beatStruct);
        }
        else
        {
            int numberOfLevels = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("LevelCount",-1);
            int cont = 0;

            // - Search for correct difficulty place
            while ( cont < numberOfLevels && CompareDifficulties( PlayerPrefs.GetString (cont + "Difficulty") , trackDiff ) > 0 )
                cont++;


            auxDiff = PlayerPrefs.GetString (cont + "Difficulty");
            auxName = PlayerPrefs.GetString (cont + "Name");

            if ( CompareDifficulties(trackDiff, auxDiff) == 0 )
                // - Search for correct space for name
                while ( cont < numberOfLevels && CompareDifficulties(trackDiff, auxDiff) == 0 && 
                       inputLevelName.text.CompareTo (auxName) > 0 )
                {
                        cont++;
                        auxName = PlayerPrefs.GetString (cont + "Name");
                        auxDiff = PlayerPrefs.GetString (cont + "Difficulty");
                }

            auxName = PlayerPrefs.GetString (cont + "Name");

            if ( CompareDifficulties(trackDiff, auxDiff) == 0 && inputLevelName.text.CompareTo (auxName) == 0 ) // -- Replace existing track
            {
                // - Update or replace
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("CurrentLevel", cont);
                SaveTrackInPosition(PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("CurrentLevel"), inputLevelName.text, trackDiff, beatStruct);
            } 
            else if (cont >= numberOfLevels) 
            {
                // - Insert at last
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("LevelCount", numberOfLevels + 1);

                PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("CurrentLevel", numberOfLevels);
                SaveTrackInPosition(PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("CurrentLevel"), inputLevelName.text, trackDiff, beatStruct);
            }
            else if( CompareDifficulties(trackDiff, auxDiff) > 0 || (CompareDifficulties(trackDiff, auxDiff) == 0 && inputLevelName.text.CompareTo (auxName) < 0) )
            {
                // - Move and insert
                Track auxTrack;

                PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("LevelCount", numberOfLevels + 1);

                for (int i = numberOfLevels; i > cont; i--) // -- Move everything one position to the right
                {
                    auxTrack = GetTrackFromPosition ( i - 1 );
                    SaveTrackInPosition ( i, auxTrack.name, auxTrack.difficulty, auxTrack.beatTrack );
                }

                PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("CurrentLevel", cont);
                SaveTrackInPosition ( cont, inputLevelName.text, trackDiff, beatStruct );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basic storing/retrieving functions:

```
public Track GetTrackFromPosition ( int position ) 
{
    Track auxTrack;

    auxTrack.name = PlayerPrefs.GetString (position + "Name");
    auxTrack.level = PlayerPrefs.GetString (position + "Level");
    auxTrack.difficulty = PlayerPrefs.GetString (position + "Difficulty");
    auxTrack.beatTrack = Serialisation.DeserialiseStruct<BeatStruct>(PlayerPrefs.GetString (auxTrack.level));

    return auxTrack;
}

public void SaveTrackInPosition ( int position, string name, string difficulty, BeatStruct beatTrack) 
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString (position + "Name", name);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString (position + "Difficulty", difficulty);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString (position + "Level", 
                           Serialisation.SerialiseStructToString<BeatStruct>(beatTrack));
}
```

Comment: @Raptor - As I said, the game is my friend's =/ I probably shouldn't post any of it.

Comment: then we can't really help.

Comment: Just post the code how you handle the PlayerPrefs saving and loading, otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: I just edited with the basic store and retrieving functions, just like I have them in my code.

Comment: Still haven't found a solution for this =/ Help?

Answer (score 0):

try to call your GetTrackFromPosition() in Awake method and call PlayerPrefs.Save() in your SaveTrackInPosition() method (after those SetString()s)

Comment: Doesn't work. Already did that (said that in the description), but I tried again just now and no, still not working in standalone.

Comment: GetTrackFromPosition() is only called in SaveLevel() (I'm editing the post right now with the function) to move tracks or consult their values. So that should not be a problem =/